# Uninstall Visual Studio Code 32bit

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install the 64bit version of Visual Studio Code but I can't figure out how to remove the 32 bit version first. I'm running Ubuntu 17.04. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge code
```

but that removes the newly installed 64 bit version.  Other things I've tried with no luck:

```
sudo dpkg --remove code
sudo dpkg --remove visual-studio-code
sudo apt-get --auto-remove visual-studio-code
sudo umake --remove ide visual-studio-code
```

I have no idea what else to try.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How did you install this 32-bit version?

Comment: @muru From what I remember I downloaded the .deb then used GDebi Package Installer to install.

Comment: Then if you installed the 64-bit version also using a deb package, it overwrote the old 32-bit version.

Comment: it didn't.  I had both installed at the same time and I could start each individually.

Comment: Do you still have the 32-bit deb file? If so, run `dpkg-deb --info /path/to/32-bit-deb-file`, and add the output to the question, please.